# How to get the Collection of an iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, apache-commons

Often there is the need to setup an `ArrayList<>`. One of the constructors takes a collection, but there is no constructor that takes an iterator.

What if I have an iterator? Is there a way to "reach up" to the collection that offers the iterator in order to use the `ArrayList<>` constructor?
Specifically I have the iterator offered by `PropertiesConfiguration.getKeys()` which is part of [org.apache.commons](http://commons.apache.org/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such thing, *an `Iterator`'s `Collection`*. An Iterator can be created independently of a `Collection`. It can be obtained from any `Iterable`, or you can even create a class implementing an iterator.

However, you can obtain an `ArrayList` from an `Iterator` by iterating it and adding its elements one by one:

```
Iterator<X> it = ...;
List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  list.add(it.next());
}
```

Note, however, that this cannot be done reliably for every possible iterator, since there's the possibility that an iterator will iterate forever, thus causing an infinite loop and most probably an `OutOfMemoryError`.

I'd suggest you take a look at [**Google Guava**](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), an utility library from Google. It has a class called Lists, which allows you to do the following:

```
Iterator<X> it = ...;
List<X> list = Lists.newArrayList(it);
```

The library has tons of methods extremely useful for everyday Java coding. It contains mostly everything you want but cannot find in the standard Java 6 API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *truly general* way to do this, because in Java, `Iterator` is just an interface with three methods: `next`, `hasNext` and `remove`.

When you obtain an iterator, you use a factory method that gives you an instance of some class implementing the interface.  If you know the specific class, you can look at its documentation or source to find if there is a way to find the collection it is iterating over.

But there are many such classes.  In the case of `ArrayList`, look in the source code to see what kind of iterator you are getting.

**EDIT**:

Here is the source code for `ArrayList` in Open JDK 7: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html

The iterator over an `ArrayList` is an instance of the *private* inner class `Itr`.  This should not be too surprising.  The iterator comes from a factory method, after all, so you're really not supposed to know what kind of iterator you are getting.  In fact, if you *were* able to get the class of this instance and access its methods (say, via reflection) you would be doing a bad thing.  This iterator is part of the (internal) implementation of the `ArrayList` class and (as @merryprankster points out) can change in the future.

Comment: Then again, you should not rely on internal details of `ArrayList` implementation as there are no guarantees that 'compatibility' will be retained. See Apache Commons Collections, `IteratorUtils` in particular. It provides some helpers to transform Iterator into an array or list.

Comment: Oh definitely, good point. There is a reason the iterator interface is restricted and the actual object returned from the factory is an instance of a private class (as it allows the implementation to change in the future).  These things are not to be touched and yes I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Ray Total: any well design classes that produces an Iterator will make it impossible to access it's internal data structure without using black magic from java.lang.reflect

Comment: It appears I misunderstood the OP's question completely.  It was titled "How do I get the collection from an iterator" and that was the question I was answering.  Completely in agreement that this is not something that should not be done.  Good suggestion about Guava, BTW. +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its possible, but in my opinion, a such function should not exist because an iterator may not come from a collection. For example, one could create an iterator which chains over multiple collections !